# Put one image below other one

Tags: c#, gdi+, photos

Im not good in working with pictures, what I want is to merge two pictures, but I need a i second picture to be below the first one.
Like

> [Image1]
>   
>   [Image2]

Example: I have two images of the size 320x240px. I want an image 320x480px with the content of Image1 in the top half and Image2 in the bottom half.

Comment: html, gdi+, wpf, sl? can you provide more details?

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a new image which contains the original two stuck together?

Comment: If you only want to do this once, maybe consider a graphics editing program?

Comment: Sorry, C#, I forgot to add C# at the start of the title.

Comment: @Tharwen Yes, exactly what I mean.

Comment: C# is a programming language. it does not describe in what framework/library.

Comment: Do you mean that if you have two input image sources with the size 320x240px you'll end up with one output image 320x480px?

Comment: @DanielA.White Sorry, I ment gdi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
        Image image1 = GetFirstImage();

        Image image2 = GetSecondImage();

        var bitmapImage = new Bitmap(Math.Max(image1.Width, image2.Width), (image1.Height + image2.Height));
```

//.....

```
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapImage))
        {
            g.DrawImage(image1, 0, 0);
            g.DrawImage(image2, 0, image1.Height);
        }
```

Comment: This is the best answer!

Comment: I decided to revote my accepted answer to this one.

Answer (score 2):

This link will take you through a full tutorial of exactly what you want to do: [Web Archive - Combining Images with C#](http://web.archive.org/web/20130214003927/http://tech.pro/tutorial/921/combining-images-with-csharp)

In the tutorial, the author first creates a List of image objects and then iterates through the list adding each image to a new merged image.  It's a bit of overkill for what you're trying to do but it is a full code solution.

Comment: Clear, easy to understand, exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Site is down right now.  Could you possibly elaborate on your answer?  I know it was a long while ago, but the answer is useless without the site being operational.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this simple code below will be helpfull for you.

```cs
// bitmap1 is a first image (320, 240).
// bitmap2 is a first image (320, 240).
// newBitmap is a final image (320, 480).

var newBitmap = new Bitmap(320, 480);
var newBitmapGraphics = Graphics.FromBitmap(newBitmap);
newBitmapGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap1, 0, 0);
newBitmapGraphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap2, 0, 240);
```